# Cannot read property 'map' of undefined - ReactJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, loops, mapping, axios

So i've done an axios get request to a yelp api. I can get the data, as I am console.logging 20 results in an object array.

However, when I try to map through my results, I get two errors in my console:

**app.js:53912 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined**
and
**Unhandled rejection TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined**

Not sure, what I'm doing wrong....

Here is the code for the axios request...  perhaps this isn't assigning data to me state properly:

```
 getYelp = () => {
// const params = {lat: this.state.lat, lng: this.state.lng};
const params = {latitude: 34.019864, longitude: -118.490541 };
const urlProxy = 'https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://api.yelp.com/v3/businesses/search';
Promise.props({
  businesses: axios({
    url: urlProxy,
    params: params,
    json: true,
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
      'Authorization': 'Bearer MY_API_KEY',
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': '*',
      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': 'http://localhost:8000'
    }
  })
    .then(res => console.log('YELP', res.data.businesses))
    // .then(res => res.data)
    .catch(err => console.log(err))
 })
  .then(data => {
    this.setState({
      businesses: data.businesses
    });
  });
 }
```

And here's the mapping code:

```
    <section className="section">
      <div className="has-text-centered">
        <h1 className="has-text-centered cat-titles">YELP:</h1>
      </div>
      <ul className="columns is-multiline">
        {this.state.businesses.map((business, i) =>
          <li key={i} className="column is-one-third">
            <div className="container card">
              <div className="">
                <div className="card-image">
                  <figure className="box">


                    <p className="is-size-4 has-text-left has-text-black">{business.name}</p>
                    <p className="has-text-left">{business.name}</p>

                  </figure>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </li>)}
      </ul>
    </section>
```

I'm running the getYelp(); function in componentDidMount.

And I have another axios request pulling through/mapping data fine on the page too.  Just can't figure out what I've missed here...

**UPDATED!!!**

I'm including the full page code here:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import axios from 'axios';
import Promise from 'bluebird';
import '../../assets/scss/main.scss';

import GoogleMaps from '../../components/common/GoogleMaps';
import Footer from '../../components/common/Footer';
// import Darksky from '../../components/common/Darksky';


// const rp = require('request-promise');

class Hub extends React.Component {

state =  {
  places: null,
  articles: null,
  user: null,
  // latlng: null
  lat: null,
  lng: null,
  businesses: []
}

 setLocation = (lat, lng) => {
   console.log('location set...', lat, lng);
   this.setState({ lat: lat, lng: lng }, this.getPlaces);
 }

getYelp = () => {
// const params = {lat: this.state.lat, lng: this.state.lng};
const params = {latitude: 34.019864, longitude: -118.490541 };
const urlProxy = 'https://cors- 
   anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://api.yelp.com/v3/businesses/search';
   Promise.props({
     businesses: axios({
       url: urlProxy,
       params: params,
       json: true,
       method: 'GET',
       // withCredentials: true,
       headers: {
         'Authorization': 'Bearer MY_API_KEY',
         'Accept': 'application/json',
         'Content-Type': 'application/json',
         // 'Origin': 'http://localhost:8000',
         'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': '*',
         'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': 'http://localhost:8000'
       }
     })
    .then(res => console.log('YELP', res.data.businesses))
    // .then(res => res.data)
    .catch(err => console.log(err))
})
  .then(data => {
    this.setState({
      businesses: data.businesses
    });
  });
}

 componentDidMount() {
  this.getYelp();
 }

 render() {
 console.log('PLACES', this.state.places);

// if businesses is null/false and nothing has loaded, dont run the 
code below.
// if businesses is truthy, then run code below
if (!this.state.businesses) return false;
return (

  <main>
    <section className="hero hub-image section-top">
      <div className="hero-body no-padding">
        <div className="has-text-centered">
          <h1 className="hub-title">Your Travel Hub</h1>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
    {/* <Darksky /> */}

    <section className="section">
      <div className="columns">
        <div className="column">
          <GoogleMaps setLocation={this.setLocation} />
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>

    <section className="section">
      <div className="has-text-centered">
        <h1 className="has-text-centered cat-titles">YELP:</h1>
      </div>
      <ul className="columns is-multiline">
        {this.state.businesses.map((business, i) =>
          <li key={i} className="column is-one-third">
            <div className="container card">
              <div className="">
                <div className="card-image">
                  <figure className="box">


                    <p className="is-size-4 has-text-left has-text-black">{business.name}</p>
                    <p className="has-text-left">{business.name}</p>

                  </figure>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </li>)}
      </ul>
    </section>

    <Footer />
  </main>
   );
 }
}
export default Hub;
```

Comment: Change `componentDIdMount` to `ComponentWillMount` .

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You should check this.state.business exists before doing a map.

```
const business = this.state.business ? this.state.business : [];
```

then do a map over business

Live sample code

https://codesandbox.io/s/24r49nyp5p

Comment: you can not `map` over a string.

Comment: Hiya, I've updated my question to include all my page code.

I've also taken someone's recommendation - I understand it wont map, because businesses is undefined.  But how and where do I define this?

The data is accessible from the axios call....  Not sure  if maybe it's not actually being assigned to state though??

Comment: Now I get the following in console:

`code` Can't call setState (or forceUpdate) on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in the componentWillUnmount method. in GoogleMap (created by Hub) in div (created by Hub) in div (created by Hub) in section (created by Hub) in main (created by Hub) –`code`

Comment: Hi, could you please create a code example on codesandbox.io I will look into

Comment: @MontyGoldy Hiya, it's a big app :)

Here's the live page, where you can see all the console logs.  
https://hit-me-up-app.herokuapp.com/hub

I've actually gotten the data to set to state now.  So that's working, I just can't get it to map through my data now.  I get the following error in console:

this.state.businesses.map is not a function

I've also dumped my code here as requested.  but doesn't actually work, but the code is the exact code i'm using...

Comment: @ReenaVerma Hi I tried to run your getYelp()  function using my foursquare api details. Added a constructor and removed your truthy condition as well and removed axios Promise as well. The problem I believe is promise chain as when I tried with your code I was unable to hit fetch api. Added live code sample in the original post.

Answer (score 0):

`componentDidMount` is called when component's `jsx` is executed. Your `jsx` has a call of `this.state.businesses`, but it probably not defined, as it gets defined only after `mount`.

Comment: Ok, so how do I define this?

Comment: assign `state.bussinesses` to `[]` as default property

Comment: when `this.setState(...)` will be called, then `render` method will be recalled

Answer (score 0):

Although you didn't show your code for the constructor, the first issue that comes to my mind is that your `businesses` inside the `state` is not defined.

Please in your constructor put the following code:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
        businesses: [],
    }
}
```

This will solve your problem.

**Cause:** you are trying to loop with a `map` of an undefined variable, you are not taking into account the time that your axios calls take to solve and save the values into the state (with time I mean the time of the request/response)

Comment: I do have businesses defined in state, I've updated my question so you can see all my code...